# How do I set Ubuntu server to two static IP addresses and proper routing with two interfaces

Tags: ubuntu, routing, route, interface

I'm trying to set up the routing table on Ubuntu 12.04. The network environment is as follows:

```
server -----eth0 192.168.0.1 (DMZ)---LAN----10.13.x.x
```

Because the communication between 192.168.0.1 and LAN is too heavy, the firewall will crash. Therefore, I try to temporarily and a interface to server so that we can bypass the firewall. The configuration is as follows.

```
        ---eth0 192.168.0.1(DMZ)
       |
server-----eth1 10.13.0.1 (LAN)
```

When the eth1 is up, a host(10.13.x.x) in the lan can ping eth1 but can not ping eht0. The routing tables is as follows

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.13.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

How do i set the routing table so that a host in the lan can connection with eth0 and eth1 simultaneously (The host with ip address 10.13.x.x can ping eth1 and eth2)?

Comment: Did you enable IP forwarding on the server machine? I do however think that this question is more appropriate for superuser.com or askubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable ip_forwarding in the server.

You can do this by editing  `/etc/sysctl.conf` and changing:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```